# I have some troubles with my code

Tags: c

I'm having some troubles with my code. I'm running the code I put the teams like Madrid - Barça and then in File only appears Madrid. Otherwise if I put only Barça, the file don't recognize 'ç'.

```
while (camp<5) {
  printf("Altere Jogos da Liga dos Campeões %d: ", camp+1);
  scanf("%s", futebol[camp].campeoes);
  while (getchar() != '\n');
  camp++;
}

feventosDesportivosFutebol = fopen("EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt", "w");
if (feventosDesportivosFutebol != NULL) {
  fprintf(feventosDesportivosFutebol, "\n\nLiga dos Campeões:\n\n");
  for (camp = 0; camp<5; camp++) {
    fprintf(feventosDesportivosFutebol, "%s\n", futebol[camp].campeoes);
  }
}
fclose( feventosDesportivosFutebol);
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: when asking a rumtime question:  post a short code that cleanly compiles and shows the problem  post the actual input.  post the actual output, post the expected output.

Comment: " I put the teams like Madrid - Barça and then in File only appears Madrid" --> `scanf("%s", futebol[camp].campeoes);` , does not save spaces in `futebol[camp].campeoes`

Comment: "... the file don't recognize 'ç'." --> How did you determine this - what did you see?  What tool was used to read the file?

Comment: I clipboard copied your text `Barça` and pasted that as console input to a simple `scanf("%s", str)` program and the output was: `Barça`.

Comment: To expand on what @chux said, when using the %s format descriptor, scanf() will read the first space-delimited set of characters input, so it will quit reading upon encountering the space following the 5 characters "Barça"/

Comment: @FredK but, the question says: "if I put only Barça, the file don't recognize 'ç'."

Comment: So, what I have to change? And How will I change?

Comment: "what I have to change? " --> Responding to [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352195/i-have-some-troubles-with-my-code#comment69906273_41352195) asked is a good first step.

Comment: the tool is

int x;

feventosDesportivosFutebol = fopen 

("EventosDesportivosFutebol.txt","r");

if (feventosDesportivosFutebol == NULL){

       printf("Error!");

} else {

     while ((x = fgetc(feventosDesportivosFutebol)) != EOF)

    {

     printf("%c", x);

     
    }

    fclose(feventosDesportivosFutebol);

    getchar();

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n");
}